# How to make a search bar that search content of an external .txt file?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, search

Please scroll down as I did update the content, or read from here to understand what I want.

I was wondering if an expert could help me out :)
I'm making a website (not my very best side :D ) that lets users search for their ID if they are banned or not.

**Basically this is how it should work:**

1. Users put in 'data'. (ex. 123456789987654321 )
2. User press 'Search' button.
3. *The search script begins after here*.
4. 'It', *'The Web script that I want'*, goes to the custom URL to search (ex. www.website.com/bans.txt) (URL that I want needs to be uneditable - Only I can edit the URL so users never know the URL or can change it)
5. If 'it' *finds* the 'data' than he gives response to client. *(If he finds it he says: 'You are banned.' |OR| If he doesn't find it he says: 'You are not banned.')*

I did make a lot of search work. But I couldn't find anything to get to work. I even followed tut's from YouTube but they were all over searching from a file that was already on the machine. What I search is it searches from a URL. (it is also a txet file but on a external site than the search script will be on.)

I did try my best to explain what I try to make. I hope someone will help me out, did spend 5 hours to find something...

**--UPDATE--**

I did make a searchbar that looks like this:

```
<div class="search-container">

                            <form action="search.php">
                                <input type="text" placeholder="Add your UID here" name="search">
                                <button type="submit">Search | Am I Banned?</button>
                            </form>
                        </div>
```

Than I did add a php file like @Justin T. said and it looks like this:

```
    <?php

$userSearchString = $_POST['searchStrFromForm'];

$secretURL = "censored";
$urlContents=file_get_contents($secretURL);

if(strstr($urlContents,$userSearchString)!=FALSE){
  //found
  echo "You are banned.";
}else{
  //not found
  echo "You are not banned.";
}

?>
```

However this is not wirking I always get - You are not banned. - as response even if the UID (string that the user searches) exist on that peac of .txt file.

If you want a demo pleas go [here](http://leventhan.info/banlist/) and type 'asdasd' wich is not exist in the UID's list and than try typing '76561198151285096' wich it is in the list but still you will see -> You are not banned.

Comment: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/1415724).

Comment: I'm feeling a https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem ; Like how will you obscure the URL? Handle it from an API? Is there a 3rd party API or do you have to screen scrape?

Comment: we haven't got any code to look at so we cannot possibly know why it's not working, sorry

Comment: BTW, a txt file is probably not the best solution here.  There are a lot of ways of storing data that come with all sorts of nice tools for searching and parsing that you wont get out of that txt file.  If you want to keep it really simple, an XML or JSON file would be much better, but if you want something more scalable, you should look into a SQL database (SQL server, mySQL, Oracle, PostgreSQL, etc...)  Also, if you want to block people by IP address in addition to user accounts, you may read up on .htaccess files.

Comment: Tried to change the content and title - I hope now it is clean to understand. I don't need any API it is just a clean search bar that will do a fast check from a .txt wich is at a external URL...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would handle the user's input using PHP and use [file_get_contents()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) to load the contents from the URL you specify into a variable, then search through the variable for the search text using [strstr()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php) and other PHP search functions.

Your PHP code would look something like this...

```
<?php

$userSearchString = $_POST['searchStrFromForm'];

$secretURL = "http://www.yoursecreturl.com";
$urlContents=file_get_contents($secretURL);

if(strstr($urlContents,$userSearchString)!=FALSE){
  //found
  echo "You are banned.";
}else{
  //not found
  echo "You are not banned.";
}

?>
```

I have not tested this and it may need some tweaking, but should hopefully get you down the right path. Good luck!

Comment: I did add this however - Even if I write a string that is in that url he returns else... So he says not found, always. If it exist or not he always says You are not banned.
Can someone help me out to fix it? (I'm sure that searchbar in html and php code you gave are good but maybe we need to add something else?)

Comment: I just tested it and it works for me. Can you post your HTML and PHP code?

Comment: I did post everything you can use :)

Comment: You forgot to change the $_POST variable. In you PHP, change "$userSearchString = $_POST['searchStrFromForm'];" to this... "$userSearchString = $_POST['search'];". In your HTML, change "<form action="search.php">" to this... "<form action="search.php" method="POST">" and you should be good to go!

Comment: Thanks for response Justin :) But still it says: You are not banned - when it should say I'm banned.

Comment: You did not add the method="POST" attribute to your form tag... make your opening form tag in the HTML look like this... "<form action="search.php" method="POST">"

Comment: YOU ARE MY HERO <3 WORKING

Comment: Glad I could help :) Good luck with the rest of the project!